# Check a date input is greater than the systemDate ( dateTime.now) in ionic 2

Tags: validation, datetime, ionic2

i have this input for the date i want to check if it's greater than the actual date or not! please i need help

```
 <ion-item>
     <ion-label color="appbase">Date</ion-label>
     <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD" min="2016" max="2020-10-31" 
     [(ngModel)]="datExpModel" formControlName="date_expiration"></ion-
     datetime>
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: when i select a date if it's not greater than the actual date i want a popup to show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the documentation of ion-datetime

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

In particular the (ionChange) output event, where could compare the dates. In order to easily calculate/modify dates, I suggest you to take a look at the moment.js library.

https://momentjs.com/

Hope this was helpfull